# Facebook counting box

Tags: facebook, count, inline, facebook-like

I want to get a Facebook Like button for my site. I want to create one with a button count to the right of the button.

Only if i create one with my own url the display style changes, and it gives an inline count of the likes. I dont want that. I want the count to display to the right of the button.

Does someone knows how to do that? Cause for example if you type in  'http://betaalsociaal.nl/' in the Like generator it does another display style then if i do another url. Why is that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is just how Facebook's custom Like control works.  You can change the layout style, I believe the style you're after is `button_count`.

```
<fb:like href="" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" font=""></fb:like
```

Comment: you're right. but how to get my button count outside the button rather then inside the button?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean to the right of the like button?  The 'button_count' layout has a like button, with the count to the right of it just like you're asking.  It's not inside the button.  You may have to specify the layout attribute for each url otherwise it may use a default.  Have you seen a page somewhere that uses the Like button how you're wanting to?

Answer (score 1):

In this page, there's an option for styles... pick one you like:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

The one you want is button_count.

If you want to know how many like's your page has programmaticly, you could use the JSON object:"https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=YOURPAGEURL/"

Comment: i appreciate your reply, but the thing i want is the like count to be displayed on the side and not in the button itself. you know how i do that? cause if i type in the url it changes the appearance (i'm sorry maybe i didnt make my self really clear in the first post)